# MIN on a date field

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am using an Oracle database.

Is it possible to apply a `MIN` to a date field, as follows:

```
MIN(TO_DATE(Person.birthday, 'DD-Mon-YY'))
```

Comment: Of course, why don't you simply try it?

Comment: If it's already a date field, simply use `MIN(person.birthday)`

Comment: Column, not field...

Comment: What data type is `birthday`? If it is a `date` column using `to_date()` to convert a `date` value to a `date` value does not make any sense (and might even lead to an error if your current NLS date format is not `dd-mon-yy` - it would fail on my computer for example)

Comment: And yes, it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0e3c1/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple question but there's a **big** catch to it.

**Is it possible to apply** `MIN` **to date column ?**

- Yes you can.

**Is this the correct way** `MIN(TO_DATE(Person.birthday, 'DD-Mon-YY'))` ?

- No. You should use `MIN(Person.birthday)` If the column is already
  `DATE` type, you should not use `TO_DATE` to convert it again as
  ORACLE converts it implicitly.

Here's an example why -

**DATA** -

```
+-------+--------+-----------+------+-------------+------+------+--------+
| EMPNO | ENAME  |    JOB    | MGR  |  HIREDATE   | SAL  | COMM | DEPTNO |
+-------+--------+-----------+------+-------------+------+------+--------+
|  7369 | SMITH  | CLERK     | 7902 | 17/Dec/1980 |  800 |      |     20 |
|  7499 | ALLEN  | SALESMAN  | 7698 | 20/Feb/1981 | 1600 |  300 |     30 |
|  7521 | WARD   | SALESMAN  | 7698 | 22/Feb/1981 | 1250 |  500 |     30 |
+-------+--------+-----------+------+-------------+------+------+--------+
```

**QUERY 1**

```
select MIN(TO_DATE(hiredate, 'DD-Mon-YY')) from emp;
```

**RESULT 1**

```
17/12/2080
```

**QUERY 2**

```
select MIN(hiredate) from emp;
```

**RESULT 2**

```
17/12/1980
```

As you can see the century is messed up when you use `TO_DATE` function in QUERY 1. However, the result is as expected in QUERY 2

> If you **necessarily** have to use `TO_DATE` function, I would suggest
>   you to use `DD-Mon-RR` format as it takes care of the century
>   mismatch. *This format was created when the problem for year Y2K (the Millennium bug) came up*. However, I still wouldn't advise to go for it.

EDIT 1:

I am not sure how `Person.birthday` is a valid column name. Can anyone enlighten me on this ?

Comment: The incorrect usage of `to_date()` might not just return invalid data, it might also result in an error. On my computer I get "*ORA-01843: not a valid month*" when using `MIN(TO_DATE(hiredate, 'DD-Mon-YY'))` because my `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is **not** `DD-MON-YY'

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I couldn't agree more. `TO_DATE` is just not meant for `DATE` column. It was created to convert strings to date.

Comment: ... from person <no alias>